# Change Internal and external URL's for Office Web Apps Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, owa, wopi

we have configured the OWA farm, but both the internal and external URL's are the same.

how do I change the URL's.
[image: OWAFARM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the below command to change the external url to the desired one.

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -ExternalURL "url"
```

[Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219442.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I have changed the internal and external URL's.  The web application calling it has a default zone and an AAM of Intranet Zone. The intranet zone is still calling the internal URL, is it because it is set up at the Intranet zone?

Comment: I tried running the /hosting/discovery and it works for the internal link but it doesn't work for the external url

Comment: if you want to run the external zone as well then the wopi command should be like this Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https" ....if you already run the command with internal then remove it and run the above

Comment: how to remove it, i did run the Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https" comman and atm it is showing WOPIZone as external https

Comment: Get-SPWopiZone  & Get-SPWOPIBinding, are the output same for both commands?

Comment: Yes they both are showing external-https

Comment: then it should work

Comment: its working on the internal url through, even the intranet zone is accessing internal url.

Comment: what that mean? if it is not working for external users, then i would delete the bindings Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All:$true then recreate it with external url Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https"